# How to add a checkbox inside the "Publish post" widget?

Tags: actions, publish

I'm building  post to email plugin and I need to add a checkbox to the publish post widget like this one:

[image]

My idea is to add a checkbox that says "Send this by email", and get that info inside the publish_post listener:

```
add_action('publish_post', function($post_id) {
     // Was the checkbox checked?
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What's the exact question? Have you inspected `$_POST` inside the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook into `post_submitbox_misc_actions` and print the checkbox:

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', function() {
    ?>
<div class="misc-pub-section">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> click me</label>
</div>
    <?php
});
```

Wrap the code in a `<div class="misc-pub-section">`, otherwise the spacing looks a little bit weird.

Examples: [language selector](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85394/73), [noindex checkbox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/118729/73), [public preview checkbox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116659/73).