# What Can I Use To Add A Custom Button Between Publish button and Move To Trash?

Tags: posts, customization, metabox, publish, buttons

I want to insert a custom button between "Publish" button and "Move To Trash" link. What can I use to make this?

Here is a screenshot to make this clearer:

[image]

I know I can use jQuery, but I want to do it the wordpress way. May be there is a filter hook or something else for it?

Comment: See also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161231/how-to-add-a-checkbox-inside-the-publish-post-widget

Comment: It is not inserting in between the two stuffs, but before them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an action *before* the *Trash* link: `post_submitbox_start`.

You can use it to add content to that box. The *Trash* has a `float:left`, so it will move to the side.

Example:

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_start', function() {
    print '<button>Hey!</button>';
});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It is still adding it before the default stuffs. But I think it is the only way. Are we have a chance to ask wordpress to add a hook between `Move to Trash` and `Publish` button?

Comment: @SoursopTree Sure, open a ticket, provide a use case, and maybe even a patch.